# is_dir returns false when remote debugging from PHPStorm

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm, relative-path

Im running some remote debugging using PHPStorm on PHPUnit tests and I've run into a bit of a problem.

Everything runs fine, but when I try to run is_dir it returns false on a relative path, where when it is run from the command line it returns true.

```
is_dir("/path/to/files");
```

I assume that for some reason, although PHPStorm understands the file structure, for some reason PHP is not understanding it.

When runniing from PHPStorm, the following values are printing:

```
getcwd() 
/var/www/html/MinuteByMinuteBundle/Tests/Services/Crunch

$path
src/MinuteByMinuteBundleTest
```

When running from the command line, the following values are different:

```
getcwd() 
/Users/user/dev/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that PHPStorm has an option to set a custom working directory when specifying a test to run.

Go to `Run -> edit configurations -> [your test]`

Changed the `custom working directory` to match that being output by the terminal run:

```
/Users/user/dev
```